# how to run a server in one terminal and open another terminal and run the client using bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, web, sh

i use ubuntu 20.04,using bash shell scripting i want to run the server in one terminal and open another terminal and run the client.I tried by using gnome-terminal it doesnt solve the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd clustermanagement
go run server/main.go

gnome-terminal -x sh -c "go run client/main.go;bash"
```

i tried with other commands like `gnome-terminal --bash -c "go run client/main.go; bash"`
it didn't work.

the server starts running and then if press `Ctrl+c` and stop the server then only the client is running.

i want server to run and automatically a new terminal should be opened and client should run!

Comment: Run the server in the background (with `&`), or use a proper job control system. Removing `go` tag, this isn't language specific.

Comment: hi marc,thanks it solved the problem.but i still get the warning "# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it."is there any alternative to "-e" available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not try running the server in the background using '&'

EDIT: looks like @Marc got to it first.